# Use CI_* variables when triggering new pipeline using a URL query string

Tags: gitlab

I've prepared some buttons to trigger a pipeline within gitlab, using the ~/pipelines/new url syntax. I may put a static value for the parameter ref=, like in the example below:

`https://kalimotxo.passaran.no/my_group/my_repo/tree/my_tag/-/pipelines/new?ref=main`

But I'd like to write something like;

`https://kalimotxo.passaran.no/my_group/my_repo/-/pipelines/new?ref=$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH`

Where $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH value is my_tag from 1st url

Is there a way ?

Comment: A pipeline is triggered for a ref, without a ref, you can not load a pipeline? so gitlab does not know which ref to load, and will not populate the $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH - what do you try to achieve - it might help if you state your motivation

Comment: I added some details to the questions